# ASP.NET MVC, Is it possible to code a Response.AppendToLog in one place which will act on every Request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I am using ASP.NET 4.7 and MVC5 with C# with IIS Express locally and published to Azure App Services.

I want to add something like:

```
Response.AppendToLog("XXXXX Original IP = 12.12.12.12 XXXXX");
```

Which adds an Original IP address to the request string in the "request" column in the web server log.

If I add this to a specific "get" Action this works fine. However I do not want to add this code to every Action. Is it possible to place it more centrally such that it gets executed on every "Get" / Request. This may be a simple question, but the answer alludes me at present

Thanks for any wisdom.

EDIT: Is this via Custom Action Filters?

```
 if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod=="GET")
   {
     Response.AppendToLog... //I know this will not work as Response not known.
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost know the answer. Try handling OnActionExecuted that gets you the Response.

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Get)
            {

            }
        }

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        }
    }
```

My solution to write out text:

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendToLog("OrigIP");
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mahesh. Could you elaborate a little and define how I would implement the Response.AppendToLog. Also this approach would require a [CustomAction] attribute for each relevant action which I was hoping against.

Comment: You can either decorate individual controller with CustomActionFilter, or register CustomActionFilter during Application_start event that will work for all controllers as follows.  ` public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LogActionFilterAttribute());
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, discovered the virtue of global filters. However I am unclear as to whether it is possible to issue a Response.AppendToLog via this route.